# python Multiprocessing and maxtasksperchild

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Lately I have been playing with the multiprocessing module. I updated the last version and I realized that the last version in Pypi has new code that doesn't match the documentation.

Specificaly, creating a Pool doesn't have the maxtasksperchild option, think that following the doc, is a new integration on python2.7

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

Checking the new module says the version of the multiprocessing module is 2.6.2.1
If that is true, and the argument is right, how can we now ensure that the new processes are going to free all memory? That was my main interest on using the argument. Looking at the code I didn't find anything yet, but I am still looking.

Thanks

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module is part of the standard library. If you're getting an external version, it's probably old and out of date (and intended for use on even older versions of Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Pypi's multiprocessing page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/) :

"Backport of the multiprocessing package to Python 2.4 and 2.5".

You should only use it with older python version. On python > 2.7, multiprocessing is a built-in module that you don't need to install.